# Google Picasa offline or something similar

Tags: picasa

I'll be spending some time in the near future working in a place without decent internet access, practically without any at all save for the basic mail upload/download needs.

Is it possible for the purposes of gathering and organizing photographs and videos to work with Google Picasa completely offline, saving labels, tagging people and so on? And later to transfer all of its settings & saved info to another computer without uploading it to the net?

If not, is there some other program that offers similar capabilities without needing internet access? I'm particularly interested in labeling photos, and tagging persons in photos for the purpose of catalogization and easier access later?

Comment: Don't be confused by the similarity in names between Picasa (a desktop program that will happily work offline) and Picasa Web Albums (Google's online photo gallery offering).

Comment: @RandyOrrison - Ah, so I can use it completely offline without using google's online services?

Comment: Yes - the application that you download and install on your PC does not need to be connected to the internet to work.  As Vlad says in his answer, you can upload pictures later if you want to, but you don't have to.  You can use it completely independently of Picasa Web Albums.  I have about 20,000 photos in Picasa, but I've only uploaded a few hundred that I wanted to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picasa can be used to organize photos locally, including face tags. The photos can be uploaded to web albums later or copied to another computer.